# Using LINQ to query concrete classes stored in base class tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm just starting to get my head around LINQ queries.  I've looked at the [MSDN page about type relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx), and understand the rudiments of querying.  However, I can't find anything that helps me with querying when EF6 (code first) has merged a number of concrete classes into one table based on the base class.

I have a base abstract class declared like this:

```
public abstract class Product
{
    // a whole bunch of fields, properties, and methods
}
```

and then a bunch of concrete classes declared like this:

```
public class ProductOption : Product
{
    public ProductOption()
    {
        // A bunch of stuff to set properties in the base class.
    }
}
```

Entity Framework creates a single table called `Products` that has a column named `Differentiator` with values identifying the name of the concrete class the particular row holds (e.g. `ProductOption`).  The column does not create a property in `Product`.

What I would like to do is (following the MSDN example) declare something like:

```
var queryAllProductOptions = from po in ProductOptions
                             select po;
```

I've heard from at least one person that I need to filter instead, looking something like this (luckily we have a property that helps):

```
var queryAllProductOptions = from po in Products
                             where po.Category = ProductCategory.Option
                             select po;
```

The implications of being able to use the first method are significant.  We have a workaround, but it might cause complications in certain instances (though none insurmountable).

Does the first way work, or do we need to filter Products the way the second method outlines?

Comment: Well, does the first way work? Try it out and see

Comment: Our developer is working on the code base that's executable; I'm trying to develop snippets of code that work as an output of my design work to reduce the amount of R&D he has to do when he gets around to the part where I say, "Oh, now we need to add this feature."  In short, I can't _try_ it in the state my code base is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have here is TPH inheritance.
Querying types in a TPH mapping are like this :

```
var query =
    from lodge in context.Lodgings.OfType<Resort>()
    select lodge;
```

excerpt coming from programming entity framework page 392

So did you consider the OfType yet ?

Comment: We hadn't considered that.  I'll read up on OfType<T> and see what I find.